# How to Read the JSON Payload in a JAX-RS Filter

Tags: java, filter, jersey, authorization, jax-rs

I'm trying to do a personalised authZ process prior to each api-request.

I'm using JAX-RS/Jersey.

```
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException { 
// How to see JSON payload here?

... 
}

}
```

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28634304/2587435)

Comment: Ok, this helped me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336095/how-to-read-json-request-body-in-jersey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.getEntityStream()` will contain an `InputStream` that represents the body.  You can read it there.

Comment: Ahhh yeh i did see that but I was hoping there was maybe some magical injection I could use.